# CSS transition doesn't work with react-portal

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am using `react-portal` to make a dialog and added transition, it went well as

```
// App.js
 return (
   <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Click to see dialog</button>
      <PortalDialog isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen}>
        This is content of dialog
      </PortalDialog>
      {/* animation works */}
   </div>
  )

//PortalDialog.js
  return (
    <Portal>
      <DialogWrapper className={`${isOpen ? "active" : ""}`}>
        {children}
        <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close</button>
      </DialogWrapper>
    </Portal>
  );
```

until I noticed `PortalDialog` is created every time on render which I don't want so I added a condition

```
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Click to see dialog</button>
      {isOpen && (
        <PortalDialog isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen}>
          This is content of dialog
        </PortalDialog> // animation doesn't work
      )}
    </div>
```

Now it's not rendered everytime but CSS transition doesn't work anymore and I think that's because of the condition I added. But I couldn't find a way to add transition with `react-portal`, what do I need to do here ? I made a [codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-morning-e0e2q?file=/src/App.js:199-638).

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `ReactTransitionGroup`. Check this out. https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `ReactTransitionGroup` is the answer, I wrapped my `PortalDialog` component with `CSSTransition` component as shown in their [codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-pasteur-m77l2vp00x?from-embed).

```
  <CSSTransition
      in={isOpen}
      timeout={300}
      classNames="dialog"
      unmountOnExit
    >
      <Portal>
        <DialogWrapper>
          {children}
          <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Close</button>
        </DialogWrapper>
      </Portal>
   </CSSTransition>
```

Transition is now working without being created on every render.